# moving project to a subfolder messes my script path and url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, fuelcms

I am developing the website in my local server in a root folder, the problem is that when my client told me to upload the website in to their server, it is located in the subfolder. So the url has been like this. http://example.com/myproject

The problem with that format is that all my css,js, ajax calls are messed up because when I tried to check Firebug/chrome console, I am seeing a `http://example.com/assets/css/main.css` , where in fact it should be `http://example.com/myproject/assets/css/main.css`

All my scripts are coded to be like this: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">` since that works perfectly when the project is not in a subfolder.

My question now is that, is there a trick, maybe in the .htaccess or mod_rewrite that would allow me to tell the browser that always add a /myproject in all my script calls?

The reason for this is that I don't want to change all my script calls and add a `/myproject/...`

This is the sample of my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    <Files .*>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From All
    </Files>

    # Allow asset folders through
    RewriteRule ^(fuel/modules/(.+)?/assets/(.+)) - [L]

    # Protect application and system files from being viewed
    RewriteRule ^(fuel/install/.+|fuel/crons/.+|fuel/data_backup/.+|fuel/codeigniter/.+|fuel/modules/.+|fuel/application/.+) - [F,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]

    # Prevents access to dot files (.git, .htaccess) - security.
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the .htaccess file in the document root?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main,css">` typo/comma if that's your real code.

Comment: @w3d unfortunately I don't have. But i can request if there's a solution for that.

Comment: To answer this, have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php  auto_append_file and auto_prepend_file - might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, i can't seem to imagine in using that one. Been reading it in google but still can't grasp on applying that into my current situation.

Comment: then a mod rewrite is what you could use then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- really? can you show it to me please? Thanks!

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- saw that one already

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite related questions. you'll need to work with that for a bit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok, i'll study that link you gave, thanks! deadline is already 15mins from now, just hoping that someone here in SO would offer me an already coded answer and would make me happy, else i'll be doomed. But i guess you're suggesting me to look at it myself. Thanks again :)

Comment: You could just remove the leading `/` which should not have been there in the first place. But maybe this is for your next project.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the problem with removing `/` is that when i am in this url `http://example.com/myproject/corporate/` server thinks that my css file is in `http://example.com/myproject/corporate/assets/css/main.css` even if it is in `http://example.com/myproject/assets/css/main.css`

Comment: Ok how about chnaging `/` to `./`

Comment: @RiggsFolly , still ain't working. I tried doing a `../` it works but kinda dirty. I prefer changing everything in .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable/unwilling to edit your site then you will need to edit the .htaccess file (or server config) in the site's document root. To rewrite all requests for non-existent files to your project's subdirectory:

For example, something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myproject%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule !^myproject/ /myproject/$0 [L]
```

For all requests for files not in the `/myproject` subdirectory, that don't exist, but do exist in the `/myproject` subdirectory then internally rewrite the request to the `/myproject` subdirectory.

This assumes that your (sub)site consists of real files that exist on the filesystem.

This will make it look as though your project is hosted in the document root. You could externally redirect (`R=301`) - but that would result in every page triggering multiple redirects which is to be avoided!

However, whether this works at all will depend on what else your client is hosting on their site.

I think the best solution is to edit your files.

**UPDATE:** Since your site has a *front controller* (ie. you are routing all requests for non-existent files through `index.php`) then the above directives won't quite work.

However, if the client is simply hosting a site that consists of real files on the filesystem then this could probably be simplified to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^myproject/ /myproject/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will check it out! I edited my question and added the code of my .htaccess, might give you a clue. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, I see from your existing .htaccess file that you have a _front controller_ - you are routing all requests through `index.php`. Unfortunately, my code above will not work in this instance. It could be modified (by removing the 3rd `RewriteCond` directive), however, it would mean your client would struggle to host anything else on their site - although this could perhaps be handled with some exceptions. What else does your client host?

Comment: He is hosting another custom PHP site, not a CMS, not a PHP Framework, just a basic PHP site. Not sure if that helps..

Comment: If he is hosting the "other custom PHP site" in another subdirectory then it would be relatively trivial to add an exception for that other subdirectory. However, if there are many files in the document root and other subdirectories then it's not so simple (unless there is a common pattern).

Comment: The other custom php site is in the root folder. So the files are scattered there. Then there's another folder called `myproject` where my project is located.

Comment: If the "other custom PHP site" consists of "real files" (ie. no internal rewriting of virtual requests) then this might work. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix based filesystems (which the web path is based on), the / at the beginning of a path is an absolute path to the root level.

For web addresses, this means it goes directly to the document root of your website.

You will need to remove the beginning / from your href attributes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
```

Comment: It is in Windows based systems as well!

Comment: And this is not really an answer and therefore should have been put in a comment